# Android: got InflateException and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-drawable, inflate-exception

I have a simple Activity which shows an ImageView. 
However, I sometimes receive bug report saying InflateException and OutOfMemoryError. 
And those errors are pointing to the ImageView I have used.
I have made 4 different images for mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and used in ImageView. 
File size of images: {6KB, 10KB, 14KB, 23KB}
Resolution of images: {192*192,288*288,384*384,576*576}
I believe the images is small enough that would not trigger OutOfMemoryError.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">


    <!--Below is #21-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

error trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
at SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:60)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3077)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
... 27 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
at SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:60)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3077)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
... 27 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
at SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:60)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3077)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
... 27 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3077)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
at SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:60)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *it might be* because you have set the width and height to `225dp` and your image is not natively that size. Then the Android system is having to do a resizing for you which takes more memory to copy etc. - If you can reproduce try `scaleType=cropCenter` or use `wrap_content` or change the native size of your images

Comment: could it be you use a lot of memory elsewhere and this is just the last straw?

Comment: @Henry I don't see other place that holds large memory

Comment: @Blundell will the resize operation take such a large memory for a small image?

Comment: @Blundell Or what size of image would you suggest for a Splash screen?

Comment: you could try and use a library such as glide which loads images efficiently

Comment: @AndrewV it is a good suggestion, by the way, do you know what is the exact problem?

Comment: @Season hmm it is what it is really, the best practice people say is to have a large image, scale it and load the scaled image into the memory (all done programatically). And glide just does that for you with a simple load() method.

Comment: @AndrewV well "large" is an abstract term. I do think the image I used is "small"  -_-

Comment: You should add scaleType=fitXY in image view xml

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir what is the different between fitCenter(default scale type) in terms of memory?